# sencha touch panel won't scroll after applying template

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I have a panel set to `layout: 'fit'` like all my searching suggested the problem lies.  After a JSONP request and applying a template, I can't scroll all the way to the bottom of the list.
I filled the `html: '<div>text</div>...<div>bottom</div>'` and commented out the JSONP request.  This works fine.  I left that there, then applied the template again, still no go.

My template

```
new Ext.XTemplate([
    '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div>',
                '<a href="product.html#{productid}" >',
                    '<h3>{title}</h3>',
                    '<img src="{img}" />',
                    '<p>Manufacturer: {realvendor}<br/>',
                    'Product#: {partnumber}<br/>',
                    'Manufacturer#: {vendornumber}<br/>',
                    'List Price: {msrp}<br/>',
                    'Description: {text}<br/>',
                    '</p>',
                '</a>',
                '<a href="price_av.html#{productid}" title="Price/Availablity" >Check Price</a>',
            '</div>',
    '</tpl>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much fun in console and profiles, I tracked down the problem.  It wasn't setting the height of my panel on panel.update(), but it was setting the height of the container div.
`App.views.home.setHeight(App.views.home.el.up('div').dom.style.height)`
I have a panel home in App.views which is where the template is applied. After I update the panel, I set the height to the parent object's height. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to have your panel set to vertical scroll

```
new Ext.Panel({
    // bla bla bla...
    scroll: 'vertical'
});
```